# Cannot link XML Catalog in Visual Studio Code with XML Red Hat extension

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, xsd

I use Visual Studio Code 1.46.0 (Windows 10) and *XML* extension by Red Hat 0.12.0. I cannot figure out, how to link an XSD catalog. I have these three files, all in *C:\catTest* directory:

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<textBook xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.anyurl.cox/nuecfg/1">
  <text></text>
</textBook>
```

schema.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:nuecfg="ttp://www.anyurl.cox/nuecfg" 
  nuecfg:noNamespaceSchemaUri="http://www.anyurl.cox/nuecfg/1">
  <xsd:element name="textBook">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="text" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

catalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN" "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
  <uri name="http://www.anyurl.cox/nuecfg/1" uri="./schema.xsd"/>
</catalog>
```

In XML extension setting I entered *C:/catTest/catalog.xml* (I tried both *C:\catTest\catalog.xml* and *file:///C:/catTest/catalog.xml*), but still no success - the xml complains that *Error while downloading 'http://www.anyurl.cox/nuecfg/1' to C:\Users...*.

In Eclipse with *Eclipse XML Editors and Tool 3.17* it works. In Visual Studio Code it only works with direct link *xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./schema.xsd"* (without catalog).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```json
{
 "xml.fileAssociations": [
    {
      "pattern": "settings.xml",
      "systemId": "http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"
    },
    {
      "pattern": "pom.xml",
      "systemId": "http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    }
  ]
}
```